# Remove or replace portions of a text in uitextview with animation

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, nsstring, uitextview

Suppose i have the following text in a uitextview and i want to add an animation to remove only the highlighted text in **bold** with the illusion of the text folding into the remaining string:



`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec non nunc ut justo sollicitudin interdum.
 

Sed metus augue, vehicula id accumsan sodales, eleifend quis libero. Duis iaculis ante sed lectus aliquet et aliquet neque auctor.  Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur posuere cursus dapibus. Donec euismod luctus dui ut adipiscing. Phasellus eget mauris arcu, nec commodo neque. Mauris facilisis tincidunt tellus, eget pharetra erat molestie sit amet.`

Quisque nibh neque, consequat quis facilisis non, pulvinar quis metus. Pellentesque faucibus metus a libero egestas faucibus. Nunc placerat blandit auctor. Aenean imperdiet mi et sapien facilisis laoreet. Donec adipiscing urna facilisis orci bibendum ornare. Fusce dignissim mollis eros a ornare. **Vivamus posuere, lorem nec egestas dictum, lectus dui interdum enim, vel faucibus arcu est quis quam.** Nam hendrerit molestie erat vitae iaculis. Morbi imperdiet gravida dolor, at vestibulum metus feugiat sit amet.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Well I'm not sure its possible to directly animate a `uiTextView` so you'd probably have to create a custom animation to overlay over the top to give the illusion it was animated.

Answer (score 0):

Have the text and highlight as different image layers, change the opacity of the highlight to show it appearing and then use MPFoldTransitions to flip both images.